# Convert from Tuple of strings to strings in terraform

Tags: terraform

I have an issue where I want to pass a list of vpc_ids to `aws_route53_zone` while getting the id from a couple of module calls and iterating it from the state file.

The out put format I am using is:

```
output "development_vpc_id" {
  value       = [for vpc in values(module.layout)[*] : vpc.id if vpc.environment == "development"]
  description = "VPC id for development env"
}
```

where I get the output like:

```
  "development_vpc_id": {
      "value": [
        "xxxx"
      ],
      "type": [
        "tuple",
        [
          "string"
        ]
      ]
    },
```

instead I want to achieve below:

```
  "developmemt_vpc_id": {
      "value": "xxx",
      "type": "string"
    },
```

Can someone please help me with the same.

Comment: I'm guessing it's probably because you are fetching all the outputs from the module. Can you add the module output to the question as well?

Comment: Producing a string from a sequence of strings requires deciding what syntax you'd like to use to represent the list, because a string can only contain an undifferentiated sequence of characters. Do you want to join the strings together with some delimiter like a comma between each one? or do you want to produce a string containing a JSON array? Or something else?

Comment: If you're assuming that there can only ever be one item in this list (because the `environment` value is unique across all of your VPCs) then you could use [`one`](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/one) to extract the single element from that list and return it.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't any automatic way to "convert" a sequence of strings into a single string, because you need to decide how you want to represent the multiple separate strings once you've reduced it into only a single string.

One solution would be to apply JSON encoding so that your output value is a string containing JSON array syntax:

```
output "development_vpc_id" {
  value = jsonencode([
    for vpc in values(module.layout)[*] : vpc.id
    if vpc.environment == "development"
  ])
}
```

Another possibility is to concatenate all of the strings together with a particular character as a marker to separate each one, such as a comma:

```
output "development_vpc_id" {
  value = join(",", [
    for vpc in values(module.layout)[*] : vpc.id
    if vpc.environment == "development"
  ])
}
```

If you expect that this list will always contain exactly one item -- that is, if each of your objects has a unique `environment` value -- then you could also tell Terraform about that assumption using [the `one` function](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/one):

```
output "development_vpc_id" {
  value = one([
    for vpc in values(module.layout)[*] : vpc.id
    if vpc.environment == "development"
  ])
}
```

In this case, Terraform will either return the one element of this sequence or will raise an error saying there are too many items in the sequence. The `one` function therefore acts as an assertion to help you detect if there's a bug which causes there to be more than one item in this list, rather than just silently discarding some of the items.

Comment: ```
{
  "version": 4,
  "terraform_version": "0.13.5",
  "serial": 13,
  "lineage": "6a1eb7fb-82c5-b70a-c8ec-8734102fafdd",
  "outputs": {
    "vpcs_all": {
      "value": [
        {
          "environment": "acceptance",
          "id": "xxx"
        },
        {
          "environment": "development",
          "id": "yyy"
        },
        {
          "environment": "production",
          "id": "zzz"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This is what my terraform state file contains and here I want to retrieve the vpc_id for each env after that prepare a list of it

Comment: ```
data "terraform_remote_state" "terragrunt-state-ap-south-1" {
  backend = "s3"
#  for_each = toset(local.non_primary_regions)
  config = {
    bucket = "tfstate-123456"
    key    = "x/yy/terragrunt.tfstate"
#    key    = "${each.value}/vpc-layout/terragrunt.tfstate"
    region = "eu-west-1"
  }
}
```

Comment: and this is how I am getting the state file as data so I want to retrieve the value from the state file within locals